Shortest polygonal chain with $6$ edges visiting all the vertices of a cube
I am trying to find which is the minimum total Euclidean length of all the edges of a minimum-link polygonal chain joining the $8$ vertices of a given cube, located in the Euclidean space. In detail, let the vertices of the mentioned cube be $(0,0,0)$, $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(0,0,1)$, $(1,1,0)$, $(1,0,1)$, $(0,1,1)$, and $(1,1,1)$.
Now, we know that a minimum-link polygonal chain visiting all the vertices of a cube consists of $6$ (connected) line segments, so I have finally found a valid configuration leading to a total length of $11.105\ldots$ (see Figure below).
Question: Can we prove that the minimum total length achievable (under the given constraints) cannot fall below $11.105$?


"a minimum-link polygonal chain visiting all the vertices of a cube consists of 6 (connected) line segments" - is this proved somewhere?

@MaxAlekseyev Yes, it is... for any $k$-dimensional (Euclidean) space, if $k>1$, then the minimum-link poligonal chains have $3 \cdot 2^{k-2}$ edges, as follows by Theorems 2.2 and 2.3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.11216

What happened? Has the proposed solution posted here been retired or deleted? It has just disappeared...

That answer was deleted by CommunityBot. I'm not sure what was the reason, but it looks like something happened with its author (banned?). I've cast an undelete vote - hope it'll help.

That user was "destroyed". https://mathoverflow.net/posts/472634/timeline

@GerryMyerson I cannot understand what "destroyed" means in the context. Anyway, a few days later, I received a strange, truncated, email from somebody claiming to be the OP, saying that the user account had been deleted and that he/she was trying to restore it together with the platform (?). Hoping that I haven't replied to a scam email or something like that, pretty strange. I was only interested in the posted answer since it would have solved the problem I shared here.

According to https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5850/2023-a-year-in-moderation in 2023, $403$ users were destroyed. A footnote says, A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam. A link is given to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user

My solution for the above-stated problem is provided by the $6$-link polygonal chain $(0,0,1)-(0,0,0)-\big(1+\frac{x+2+\sqrt{2}}{2\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot(x+\sqrt{2})},1+\frac{x+2+\sqrt{2}}{2\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot(x+\sqrt{2})},0\big)-\big(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\big)-\big(- \frac{x+2+\sqrt{2}}{2\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot(x+\sqrt{2})},1+\frac{x+2+\sqrt{2}}{2\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot(x+\sqrt{2})},0 \big)-(1,0,0)-(1,0,1),$
where
$x = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \sqrt{\sqrt[3]{\frac{4}{9}} \cdot \sqrt[3]{9+\sqrt{177}}-4 \cdot \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{27+3\cdot \sqrt{177}}}}  + \frac{1}{2}\cdot 
\sqrt{4 \cdot \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{27+3\cdot\sqrt{177}}} - \sqrt[3]{\frac{4}{9}}\cdot \sqrt[3]{9+\sqrt{177}} + 4 \cdot \sqrt{\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{4}{9}}\cdot\sqrt[3]{9+\sqrt{177}} - 4\cdot \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{27+3\cdot\sqrt{177}}}}}} = 1.59792093355003207476470535078046555882788360 \ldots$
whose total Euclidean length is equal to $2\cdot \big(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{2+\sqrt{2} \cdot x}{2} \cdot \big( \frac{1}{x} + \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}\big) \big) \approx 11.105251123065331797359171121524195.$
